# selenium driver scrolls the page too much

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing an emulator using selenium. I log into the discord profile, open the chat and try to click on the button under a certain message:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
# the code of entering the login, password and entering the desired chat
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'container-2sjPya')[::-1]
        count = 0
        for element in elements:
            count += 1
            try:
                image = element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".originalLink-Azwuo9")
                image_link = image.get_attribute("href")
                # text = element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"[href='{link}']").text
                if image_link == link:
                    print(f'FOUND ({count - 1}): {image_link}')
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", image)
                    element.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//*[contains(text(), 'U1')]").click()
                    time.sleep(20)
```

but this code scrolls up all the way (to the last uploaded message)
I tried to use

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(image).perform()
```

This code have same result.

Are there any other ways to scroll through the page to the desired element, and are there any errors in my code somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

With

```
arguments[0].ScrollIntoView()
```

it will always scroll to the last element. Most people use it for reaching the bottom of the page.

The documentation states:

```
element.scrollIntoView();
```

So in your case it should work with:

```
driver.execute_script("image.scrollIntoView();", image)
```

Another solution is to use the wheel implementation of selenium.

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/wheel/

Here you could use the function "scroll to element"

Comment: I tried a few more options, and it seems that the correct execution of the script does not depend on the implementation (the script is executed correctly about 1 time out of 10), because all the options I tried work on other sites, and none in discord. Are there any proven solutions specifically for discord servers?

Comment: Unfortunately i have no experience with discord, so i cant really help with that. It can help if you update your question with a "discord" tag and try to focus the question on that specific issue. Good luck